# How to calculate the number of buildings along the left/right side of a street?

Tags: spatial-database

I'm struggling to find a way to get the line direction stored on shape file from its geometry, is there any tool can get it for me?

Also, I have two layers of map: Roads layer  (of type polyline), Building layer (of type polygon)

I want to get the number of buildings located on the left, right sides of a street segment. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange @m.sai! You added a lot of tags to your question but don't mention any technology but shapefile in your question text. Could you elaborate a bit more what kind of solution you are looking for? Also it seems like you actually have two separate questions. Please post them independently.

Comment: pgRouting? (Probably I should do some homework...)

Comment: Do you want a count of the buildings on each side of a street segment, or the address numbers of each building?

Answer (score 2):

For ArcGIS you will need to build an **Address Locator** (geocoding tools)

Note: you will need clean fully attributed data to maximize your results.

Your 'Building Layer' will need to be convert to points for geocoding to work

Follow the guide on the ESRI help - there are many possible ways to do what you want.

[image]

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_geocoding/002500000002000000/

for line direction **XTools (Pro)** can show line directions
http://www.xtoolspro.com/tools.asp ('Show Directions')